how to draw line.new on recent X label candle
Following are my code in pine script.
i want to draw line.new on recent X candle. i dont want line on past X candles.
consider Close of recent X candle.
upper_line = Close + 0.09%
lower_line = Close - 0.09% extend right
i tried with various combination to pickup close of recent X candle but my code pickup cmp.
i want to mark entry if candle cross upper_line and lower_line is SL so pickup close price once X is formed. and buy candle cross Upper line `
bool newbar = ta.change(time(tf)) != 0
var label xlbl = na

bi = ta.valuewhen(newbar, bar_index, prd - 1)
len = bar_index - bi + 1

float ph = na
float pl = na

ph := ta.highestbars(high, nz(len, 1)) == 0 ? high : na
pl := ta.lowestbars(low, nz(len, 1)) == 0 ? low : na

var dir = 0
var float lastx = na
iff_1 = pl and na(ph) ? -1 : dir
dir := ph and na(pl) ? 1 : iff_1
var max_array_size = 50
var zigzag = array.new_float(0)
oldzigzag = array.copy(zigzag)

add_to_zigzag(value, bindex) =>
    array.unshift(zigzag, bindex)
    array.unshift(zigzag, value)
    if array.size(zigzag) > max_array_size
        array.pop(zigzag)
        array.pop(zigzag)

update_zigzag(value, bindex) =>
    if array.size(zigzag) == 0
        add_to_zigzag(value, bindex)
    else
        if dir == 1 and value > array.get(zigzag, 0) or dir == -1 and value < array.get(zigzag, 0)
            array.set(zigzag, 0, value)
            array.set(zigzag, 1, bindex)
        0.

bool dirchanged = dir != dir[1]
if ph or pl
    if dirchanged
        add_to_zigzag(dir == 1 ? ph : pl, bar_index)
    else
        update_zigzag(dir == 1 ? ph : pl, bar_index)

if showzigzag and array.size(zigzag) >= 4 and array.size(oldzigzag) >= 4
    var line zzline = na
    if array.get(zigzag, 0) != array.get(oldzigzag, 0) or array.get(zigzag, 1) != array.get(oldzigzag, 1)
        if array.get(zigzag, 2) == array.get(oldzigzag, 2) and array.get(zigzag, 3) == math.round(array.get(oldzigzag, 3))
            line.delete(zzline)
        zzline := line.new(x1=math.round(array.get(zigzag, 1)), y1=array.get(zigzag, 0), x2=math.round(array.get(zigzag, 3)), y2=array.get(zigzag, 2), color=dir == 1 ? upcol : dncol, width=2)
           
        xlbl = label.new(x=math.round(array.get(zigzag, 3)), y=array.get(zigzag, 2), text="X", color=color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor=color.blue, style=dir == 1 ? label.style_label_up : label.style_label_down)
        zzline
        
        
if not showzigzag and array.size(zigzag) >= 6
    var line zzline = na
    line.delete(zzline)
    zzline := line.new(x1=math.round(array.get(zigzag, 3)), y1=array.get(zigzag, 2), x2=math.round(array.get(zigzag, 5)), y2=array.get(zigzag, 4), color=dir == 1 ? color.white : color.white, width=2, style=line.style_solid)
    zzline
    



any one pls help me
